# react-native async and await problems

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous

im trying to create an app using react native
i created some static classes, contains globalDB and localDB which have data about the local database and the global database (the web db)
now i want to compare some datam and i cant resolve my problem:
i have 2 functions in 2 sepereated classes, which returns me the data of the db.
now what i want is to get a JSON from them functions, but its not working, becouse the functions are async and they require callbacks,
is there any options to get the json of the data?
what i mean by saying those are async funcs are:
from the globalDB it uses fetch, and i cant return a json from the function (it returns me a promise)
and from the localDB i use react-native-db-models, which returns me a promise and not a json
(i want in the localDB to have 1 function which will return me the whole counts, by doing this:

```
var objCounts = {};
objCounts.people = this.peopleCounts();
objCounts.example = this.exampleCounts();
etc....
)
```

if its not clear, ill try to explain this better:
i want to create a function which checks if the local database has the same rows like the server database, so lets say this function called checkData()
now, i have 2 classes: localDB and globalDB.
in every one of them there are functions which *should* return info about the data,
in localDB there are functions: getPeople, getPencils, getCounts
in globalDB there are functions: getPeople, getPencils, getCounts.
now, i want to check in checkData() if the getCounts are equal,
i mean, ill get json like:

```
[
people: "5",
pencils: "6"
]
```

in getCounts in globalDB and in localDB (maybe not the same, depends on the data on the local, but that's what i want to check)
now, i dont succeed to do it, becouse the getCounts functions returns promise..
can any1 PLEASE suggest a solution how can i reach what i want?

*UPDATE:
used mike solution, i got the data from globalDB class,
still got a problem with localDB class:
im using react-native-db-models, and calling a function get_all which requires a callback in the parameter, any idea how to transfer it to await and async?

Comment: Are you using `async await` or `Promises`? They are different things in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Promises`:

```
Promise.all([
  getPeople(),
  getPencils(),
  getCounts()
]).then(function (results) {
  console.log(results[0]); // people JSON
  console.log(results[1]); // pencils JSON
  console.log(results[2]); // counts JSON
});
```

Using `async await`:

```
async function getAll () {
  let people = await getPeople();
  let pencils = await getPencils();
  let counts = await getCounts();

  console.log(people); // people JSON
  console.log(pencils); // pencils JSON
  console.log(counts); // counts JSON
} catch (error) {
  // handle errors
}
```

For `react-native-db-models` I would try this:
(Taken from their documentation... I have not used it before and it may not work).

```
var App = React.createClass({
  get_users: async function () {
    try {
      let result = await DB.users.get_all();
      console.log(result);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  },

render: function(){
  return (
    <View>
      <Text onPress={this.get_users}> Hello </Text>
    </View>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer, i have 1 more question:
i use a library for the local db, but have some problems with creating a static helper function...
I try to make a function like localDB.getPeople(), and the problem is - i need to pass it a callback as parameter, becouse the function which gets the local data is async...
how can i return a promise so your solution would work?

Comment: Ok thank you very much!
i succeed to get the value from the globalDB,
i just need help on the localDB,
im using react-native-db-models, and calling a function get_all which requires a callback in the parameter,
any idea how to transfer it to await and async?

Comment: Updated my examples and added what might be a solution for `react-native-db-models`. I haven't used it before or tested any of this code so good luck.